# Multiple Media uploader output to input

Tags: jquery, javascript

I'm trying to select multiple images then insert the IDs (comma-seperated) into a text field.

Here's my code, but it picks the first image ID only:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var custom_uploader;
$('#media-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
    if (custom_uploader) {
        custom_uploader.open();
        return;
    }
    //Extend the wp.media object
    custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Choose Image',
        button: {
            text: 'Choose Image'
        },
        multiple: true
    });
    custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
        var selection = custom_uploader.state().get('selection');
        selection.map( function( attachment ) {
        $("#media-input").val(attachment.id);
        });
    });
    custom_uploader.open();
});
});
```

The part that should be changed is the part starting with `custom_uploader.on('select'`

Comment: You're overwriting the value of `#media-input` each time, try collecting the ids `var ids = selection.map( function( attachment ) { return attachment.id; });` and then setting the text field once `$("#media-input").val(ids.join(','));`

Comment: Can't accomplish this. Would you please post the full function code that starts with `custom_uploader.on('select'`? Thanks!

Comment: on `custom_uploader.on('select', function ()` , use `insert` instead of `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments try collecting the ids in an array and then setting the text field once:

```
            custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
                var selection = custom_uploader.state().get('selection');
                var ids = selection.map( function (attachment) {
                    return attachment.id;
                });
                $("#media-input").val(ids.join(','));
            });
```